# Excel 2013 Long delay when deleting rows in data table

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2013

I'm trying to delete 250K Row * 3 Columns, but it seems like Excel is not responding. 
Sometimes it takes more than 20 minutes to perform this, is it normal ? Can someone suggest me something, I really need to delete those rows. 
My computer specs :

```
i7 2600K @3.4Ghz
8GB Ram
Win8 Pro 64-Bit
Excel Pro 64-Bit
AMD Radeon HD 7900 Series
```

Comment: Have you tried deleting them with a macro while `screenupdating = false`?

Comment: @Raystafarian No, will this work and remove them from the data table too ?

Comment: if you turn screenupdating off, then range.delete or columns.delete or rows.delete, it will delete the data without worrying about what the user sees. Then just turn screenupdating back on.

Comment: I'm not using any code to delete them. I'm filtering all my datas, then CTRL+A & DEL, must I use VBA to put screenupdating off ?

Comment: select all and delete? You want to delete visible cells, not all cells right?

Comment: Yep I select all filtered data for deletion, which are shown after filtering the whole table

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9868/discussion-between-raystafarian-and-meds)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I'll leave the macro, but for some reason selecting the data and clearing it out, and then using table tools to remove duplicates, worked.**

*You can see troubleshooting in the chat link in the comments of the question*

---

*Once you filter the table run this macro*

```
Sub Macro1()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("TableName").DataBodyRange.Delete
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```